# How to create a dacpac from a single SQL Script

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-data-tools, dacpac

I have a SQL-Script to create a Database and some Tables. Now I want to make a dacpac from this file with comandline tools or C# Code.
I dont't want to create the database first. The goal is to create the dacpack directly on a system without VisualStudio.

Comment: I don't want to be a bother, but your best bet *is* to create the database first (a LocalDB instance would do) and export it. As far as I've been able to find out (and I did do a bit of digging myself some time back), the functionality in Visual Studio that allows it to parse files and add them to database projects is not exposed in any command-line tool or DacFx API. And a DACPAC requires a full, validated model; it cannot be used to just wrap an arbitrary SQL file.

Comment: This is incorrect the DacFx does expose the functionality to add scripts to a model, search for Dir2Dac to find it - I put an answer here but it was deleted

Comment: the Dir2Dac Solution is exactly what I'm looking for. Thx